# How to display 0 counts if value not exists in group by statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql

> My query is working fine if i dnt use where condition

```
select a.mnth,count(b.month) from table1  b right join (SELECT 'January' mnth,'01' as set_or
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'February' mnth,'02' as set_or
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'March' mnth,'03' as set_or
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'APRIL' mnth,'04' as set_or
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'MAY' mnth,'05' as set_or
                        UNION ALL
            SELECT 'JUNE' mnth,'06' as set_or
                        UNION ALL
            SELECT 'JULY' mnth,'07' as set_or
                        UNION ALL
            SELECT 'AUGUST' mnth,'08' as set_or
                        UNION ALL
            SELECT 'SEPTEMBER' mnth,'09' as set_or
                        UNION ALL
            SELECT 'OCTOBER' mnth,'10' as set_or
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'NOVEMBER' mnth,'11' as set_or
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'DECEMBER' mnth,'12' as set_or
            ) a on a.mnth = b.month   group by a.mnth  order by a.set_or asc;



+-----------+----------------+
| mnth      | count(b.month) |
+-----------+----------------+
| January   |              0 |
| February  |              0 |
| March     |              2 |
| APRIL     |              1 |
| MAY       |              0 |
| JUNE      |              1 |
| JULY      |              1 |
| AUGUST    |              0 |
| SEPTEMBER |              0 |
| OCTOBER   |              0 |
| NOVEMBER  |              0 |
| DECEMBER  |              0 |
+-----------+----------------+
```

> But i use where condion in the same query it dont display 0 against
>   every month name

```
select a.mnth,count(b.month) from table1 b right join (SELECT 'January' mnth,'01' as set_or
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'February' mnth,'02' as set_or
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'March' mnth,'03' as set_or
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'APRIL' mnth,'04' as set_or
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'MAY' mnth,'05' as set_or
                        UNION ALL
            SELECT 'JUNE' mnth,'06' as set_or
                        UNION ALL
            SELECT 'JULY' mnth,'07' as set_or
                        UNION ALL
            SELECT 'AUGUST' mnth,'08' as set_or
                        UNION ALL
            SELECT 'SEPTEMBER' mnth,'09' as set_or
                        UNION ALL
            SELECT 'OCTOBER' mnth,'10' as set_or
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'NOVEMBER' mnth,'11' as set_or
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'DECEMBER' mnth,'12' as set_or
            ) a on a.mnth = b.month  where b.year like '2016' group by a.mnth  order by a.set_or asc;


+-------+----------------+
| mnth  | count(b.month) |
+-------+----------------+
| March |              2 |
| APRIL |              1 |
| JUNE  |              1 |
| JULY  |              1 |
+-------+----------------+
```

> Here is my table description
>
> table1;

```
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| month       | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| Year        | int(100)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+------------------------------
```

> can anyone please tell me how can i get 0 counts is any months does not
>   exists?

Comment: I guess you don't have any records for those months and since using RIGHT join it does not show up, try LEFT join instead

Comment: show your table1 schema

Comment: @ scaisEdge please check my question i have added tabele description

Comment: @Boynux i do not have values against some months thats why i want to display 0 against that month

Comment: correct, that's why left join in what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rearranged order of your tables (appearance in code) and changed `RIGHT JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` respectively. Put your WHERE clause constraint into the JOIN so that no `INNER JOIN` is implied:

```
select 
  a.mnth,
  count(b.month)
from (
  SELECT 'January' mnth,'01' as set_or
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'February' mnth,'02' as set_or
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'March' mnth,'03' as set_or
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'APRIL' mnth,'04' as set_or
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MAY' mnth,'05' as set_or
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JUNE' mnth,'06' as set_or
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JULY' mnth,'07' as set_or
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AUGUST' mnth,'08' as set_or
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'SEPTEMBER' mnth,'09' as set_or
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'OCTOBER' mnth,'10' as set_or
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NOVEMBER' mnth,'11' as set_or
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DECEMBER' mnth,'12' as set_or
  ) a 
left join donation_entry b on 
  a.mnth = b.month 
  and b.year = '2016' -- here is the change
group by a.mnth
order by a.set_or asc;
```

Note that I've also replaced `like` with equality operator `=` since without wildcards for partial matching it is essentially the same and avoids confusion.