# How to show zero count in my query?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I let my query also output the 0 count results? I have seen many examples on how to do this, but I get stuck when I'm trying to apply those to my own query.

```
SELECT device.type, COUNT(device.type) AS count 
FROM devices 
WHERE device.type IN ('type1', 'type2')
```

Where for example `type2` does not exist in the device table.

Thanks a lot for your help and sorry if you think this question should better not be shared here.

Comment: The values `type1`, `type2`... have to exist somewhere in the database. If they don't you have to add the `0` rows in the application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937669/how-to-display-0-counts-if-value-not-exists-in-group-by-statement-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t.type, COUNT(device.type) AS count 
FROM 
    (select 'type1' as type
     union all
     select 'type2' as type) t LEFT JOIN
    devices on devices.type=t.type
GROUP BY t.type
```

Comment: The only thing that is not showing up here, is the type that does not exist. Is it possible to add this?

Comment: @Klyner You may be missing the point of this (and other) answers is that the subquery aliased here as `t` contains all the device types you want to cover.  If something is missing, then you add it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, nice. My question is actually solved but now my output for `type2` that does not exist in table devices is `null` in the output. (output now is like `type: null count: 0 | type: type1 count: 1`. Instead of `null` I'd rather see `type2`

Comment: @Klyner That's because `SELECT` has `device.type` instead of `t.type` of the other similar answers.

Comment: @klyner it's defined in the sub query.  If you want us to debug a query put the full query text in to a question (comments are not a good place for that)

Comment: It was a problem that occured not related to this, thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

One viable approach is to maintain a table containing all devices, and then join with that:

```
SELECT
    t1.type, COUNT(t2.type) cnt
FROM all_devices_types t1
LEFT JOIN devices t2
    ON t1.type = t2.type
WHERE
    t1.type IN ('type1', 'type2')
GROUP BY t1.type
```

Here the `all_devices` table would have at least `type1` and `type2` in it (and possibly more).

Such a device table may properly be referred to as a "calendar" table, because this strategy is often used to handle a situation where a table is missing dates, but we want to report every date.

Comment: `all_devices` should probably actually just be `all_device_types`

Comment: @RaymondNijland - If `device.type` is indexed, the answers using an inline view for `device_types` will also make use of such an index.

Comment: Wouldn't it be reasonable to refer to `all_device_types` as a dimension table?

Comment: @RaymondNijland - An inline-view, a sub-query or a derived-table, they're all synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

For a short `IN` list you could make a table-like structure with `UNION ALL`, and then left-join to it:

```
SELECT
    t.Type
,   COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
(   SELECT 'type1' AS Type
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'type2' AS Type
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'type3' AS Type
) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN devices d ON d.Type=t.Type
GROUP BY t.Type
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use SUM instead of COUNT in case of NULL values

```
SELECT t.type, SUM(IF(device.type IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS count 
FROM (
  SELECT 'type1' AS type 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'type2' AS type) t 
LEFT JOIN devices ON devices.type = t.type 
GROUP BY t.type;
```